# Delete folder if same folder name exists in another location on windows

Tags: windows, cmd

I have two folder containing artist names, one of these contains artist information and the other contains artist albums. the one with artist information gets created automatically by foobar2000, and sometimes when I don't want to listen to an artist anymore I delete the folder with the music files, however, with the passing of time I've accumulated tons of info of artist I no longer listen to, so I want somehow delete the artist info folder if such folder does not exist in the music files folder

Artist info folders: C:\Users\%username%\Artists\%Artist%
Artist music files: C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\Music\%Artist%

I'm guessing this can be done in cmd, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@echo off

pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Artists"
for /d %%d in (*) do (
  if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Music\%%~nxd\" rd /s /q "%%~d"
)
popd
```